# Extracting figures(Form Xobjects) from scientific papers

Tags: pdf, mupdf

In scientific papers, figures are often PDF files later compiled into main file by latex compilers. I'm trying to extract such kind figures from a PDF file.

Before I started exploring this topic, I had little knowledge of PDF format, so sorry if I misunderstood anything.

Take a publicly available [paper](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eswift/papers/vee20-isolation.pdf) as an example, I observed the file by opening it with text editor and found the figures are Form  Xobjects like the following one.

```
152 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Form
/FormType 1
/PTEX.FileName (./graphs/spectrum.pdf)
/PTEX.PageNumber 1
/PTEX.InfoDict 203 0 R
/BBox [135.2168 266.4003 592.6775 381.8708]
/Resources <<
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ]
/ColorSpace <<
/Cs1 204 0 R
>>/Font << /TT2 205 0 R>>
>>
/Length 1052
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x½VËn7¼ó+:/{6ÖRdóm'N`Áß-ƒÓ"‚Xdòû®&çAíZk
xˆœN³º«ºÉ[zK·d™Š¡3yÇôñú‹þ£ó‹;Kû;²õïn/«3ÝPÊ¦Î>Ô¾ü€wªŽ×tõÍáIülõdó“x7š£üfÞ'rÆØ#§@Ó;mr‰ä8êì9©
ÙkÃi¶E¸îlžXlÝ·Õ–`»î¬¶èØ<ZWtJ¡md]šöeí¸ô†P?#€[e]Bôjqäl[µ€˜,TÔÞ8Gn²Y_¦í&O‹eÙo± fG3î9_“e¯®»ì´
#x9içí"RrZ^ˆÞRADµïm"—ÎSÛžf†&¾Ë ù™rUHyÚoò´XÚ~Hr·jB5{£QË~S|{0}E%p ÿ!ù[\\®(îòBÝb‰6r)Œ*1øÛÞ7YŸuŽ6‘KV—d˜ö7uTSŽñ å$S}Íx64O¯é…%žˆ\¶dßžebƒ‡¶´eÇ:‹÷W;e³S;I¥vøµ/ºöÁÐî†Îw;FÐ»+zGÃ?n 8~Â`høÓð†¨†'ú›voèõ®ú!ìÃQ`@xÙw8B¢êÇSì\hx?làã¦¿"XÉ=Û Eí©Wsê­-Æ‡€4¢ôÇùœñ£äæœQËÞš8æ\ÜŽ9_õ(ç÷bUÇÚ“ÎlµwYfûñÉ~v~[²‘sPV?@® :¨<`    €ÿ[¬H4èº/‡2œA—tHšK¬£c·ÂÈ€:
éöœÐ!k)5ÒêZ‘ÞçZC    @¹i@‚¶-ðû÷”8ë´
(AÙ,¢Xq¤ÿïEIÉ:ù€¶~L ›’mi”´ùÒ’VÄ4¥äòg(AÎK‰`º³ äÉF    ?,2U¨Ò"ØA°X‰Ê[¼|˜*%Ú]¥j©_>—.‰ƒQ²3:¸H6h  `B“>Ä´R0¾àZÊrrtíË¹Q¦µ`Æù×·/_:t¼„oOh_Qê­B‚ÌjH`…†ÜX(søàíùaø}õ“qª¦†6Õð ”Øz`@/*/6
\üV;š ÅC¥4qÒƒ²!àtÇY¶åÌÚg«’³µ”G«øwHbÀŽÒ_å„e% ä 0"‡oÓ®œºÒt14yXÏÁààÎ‚‹×|=æKÉ2ƒ}MW‹ŠÐâ„°
HQâ€?ú"X†ªÔÑ˜¨w`OPßÓ3); ‘‹‹URk·‡³éúØ üì:´[£›îÓBøBHâCú€ì‚È€æ¾mõgOÌÛOR›Œ
endstream
endobj
```

As the name suggests, it's figure 1 in the paper. Then, I tried to extract the "graphs/spectrum.pdf" directly with `mutool extract paper.pdf` but only got font files.

Then I turned to another way — rendering the page first and extracting the pixmap using the "/BBox" attribute. The script I run with `mutool run script.js` is as follows.

```js
car pdf_path = "paper.pdf"
var doc = new Document(pdf_path);
var page = doc.loadPage(1);
var submap = new Pixmap(DeviceRGB, [135, 266, 592, 381], true)
var dev = new DrawDevice(Identity, submap)
page.run(dev, Identity, true)
submap.saveAsPNG("result.png")
```

But this way, the result PNG is not at the right place (see below). Now I'm confused by the BBox numbers...

expected result:

[image: expected result]

the result I got:

[image: result I got]

In a word, my questions are:

1. How much does the segment I pasted above tell us? Does it contain all data of the original "spectrum.pdf"?
2. Can I extract Xobjects like the one above as standalone pdf files?
3. How could I compute the final absolute location of the figures?

Comment: Thanks, @K J! I think you are right about the source being a vector graphic. Yet I'm wondering whether there's information loss during compilation, and if not, how to extract that directly. (It was once a PDF, after all.)

Comment: Yes, I guess the ultimate problem is that PDF was aiming for printouts, not distributing across the internet, yet scientific publishers only give this. 
A little context — I'm doing this with the same purposes as [paper to HTML](https://papertohtml.com/), and they are doing it with machine learning, which I doubt the necessity.

Comment: So, do you think it's doable to compute the final positions of such figures based on metadata inside the pdf file so that I could capture those areas directly?

Comment: Wow how did you extract this, it looks great! The lack of caption is fine, I guess I can write some keywords detection.

Comment: Sounds really hard to automate...

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get you. What do you mean by "how to detect that zone copy and paste the object where you want on a blank canvas not a dirty one"? I'm not a native speaker so hopefully not a language problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How much does the segment I pasted above tell us? Does it contain all data of the original "spectrum.pdf"?

No. First of all only material from the PDF required for visually including the file needs to be copied; there may be other information in the original file that is not included.

Furthermore, you see references to other indirect objects in that segment - `203 0 R`, `204 0 R`, `205 0 R` - which in turn may reference yet more indirect objects. All those objects are needed.

> 2. Can I extract Xobjects like the one above as standalone pdf files?

You can create stand-alone PDF files from Xobjects if you copy all related objects from the original file.

Beware, though, they may look differently than in the document they are extracted from. On one hand the caller of the Xobject may initialize the graphics state in a way to cause differences, and additional stuff afterwards may be drawn over the area where the Xobject has been drawn.

> 3. How could I compute the final absolute location of the figures?

In general an Xobject may be drawn an arbitrary number of times on a page (I don't know whether LaTeX compilers make use of that, though). Thus, there may not be *the* final absolute location but alternatively none (if the Xobject is not used at all) or multiple ones.

The absolute position of a use of an Xobject on a page can be calculated from the **BBox** entry of the Xobject and the current transformation matrix (a part of the graphics state) at the time it is called. To determine that CTM value you have to parse the page content streams (and possibly other - Xobject, Pattern, ... - nested content streams) and observe the changes to the CTM until the use of your Xobject.

Answer (score 1):

Some clarifications: Some of your terminology is a little confusing. Raster images are held in "Image Xobjects". "Form Xobjects" hold general PDF operator streams, either for use multiple times, or because it was simply the easiest way for the PDF producer to make the file. Of course, a Form Xobject might invoke image xobjects (or other form xobjects!). On the BBox, it refers to the bounding box of the contents of the form xobject in its own coordinate system, not its final position on the page. I don't know of any "image extraction" software which considers form xobjects to be images.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I’ve updated my description with clear questions.